# parse json string without double quads in integer value in android

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse an json string in android. String is as-

```
   String response = "[{"UserID":100055,"VisibleName":"sarita","UserSince":"September 2015"}]";
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i = 0 ; i <jArray.length();i++){

        JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    }
```

but it gives parsing exception at

```
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

org.json.JSONException: Value [{"UserID":100054,"VisibleName":"Sarita","UserSince":"September 2015"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I am using following imports

> import org.json.JSONArray;
>
> import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: there is nothing wrong in parsing.

Comment: if your response is just a string variable update as `String response = "[{\"UserID\":100055,\"VisibleName\":\"sarita\",\"UserSince\":\"September 2015\"}]";`. if it's json response from webservice then leave as such.

Comment: Use jsonlint.com to verify your json data. If it gives an error try to resolve it. And more it i suggest creating JSON Object and use put method to add data if you're using it as native code.

Comment: jsonlint.com it says valid json

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Verbatim String or Pass Escape Character for Double Quotes

```
 response = "\"{\"UserID\":100055,\"VisibleName\":\"sarita\",\"UserSince\":\"September 2015\"}\""
```

Have a Look at this :http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-work-with-json-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

just add `escape sequence` to your response string as

```
      String response = "[{\"UserID\":100055,\"VisibleName\":\"sarita\",\"UserSince\":\"September 2015\"}]";
        JSONArray jArray = null;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for(int i = 0 ; i <jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.e("value->","UserID->"+jObject.getString("UserID")+" UserSince->"+jObject.getString("UserSince")+" VisibleName->"+jObject.getString("VisibleName"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

output:

```
value->﹕ UserID->100055 UserSince->September 2015 VisibleName->sarita
```

Comment: there are escape in the string. problem  is no quads with integer value. I tried with adding quads with integer and it was parsed

Comment: First you have to convert your data into JSON format check tutorial [here](http://androhub.com/android-json-maker/).

Comment: @SurenderKumar why to convert? it's already in JSON format as string.

Comment: Oops sorry..actually i have to post this comment in above question. You are right what you have done i am giving an alternate option.